# Cannot get JSON data from URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, jsonp

Apologies for asking what looks like a frequently asked question but I cannot seem to be able to get the data from the following URL: http://www.strava.com/stream/segments/860503

I have tried the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://www.strava.com/stream/segments/860503&callback=?",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            $(document.body).append(data.latlng);
        }
    });
});
```

And:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("http://www.strava.com/stream/segments/860503&callback=?", function(data) {
        $(document.body).append(data.latlng);
    });
)};
```

But I am not having any luck. I have fiddled around with 'json' and 'jsonp', adding the '&callback=?' to the URL as well as other things suggested on SO, but to no avail.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://www.strava.com/stream/segments/860503?callback=abc&

Comment: Try this tutorial, specifically the "Load a JSON data Object from other domain" part: http://www.jquery4u.com/json/jsonp-examples/

Answer (score 0):

have you tried ? The difference being the `cb` instead of `?` at the end of the URL.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("http://www.strava.com/stream/segments/860503?callback=cb", function(data) {
        $(document.body).append(data.latlng);
    });
)};
```

Answer (score 0):

That particular URL does not support JSONP. Neither does it provide support for [Cross Origin Resource Sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin%5fresource%5fsharing) (CORS) via the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header, therefore it is impossible to directly call it via ajax.

The requirement for JSONP support is that the server must output the callback name as a function, passing the JSON as a JavaScript object or array in the argument to the function. For example:

```
myCallback({ ...... });
```

A possible solution is to proxy the ajax request through a server side script on the same domain, where cross origin is not a problem for server to server requests.

Answer (score 0):

the data from "http://www.strava.com/stream/segments/860503" has no callback. it is not made for cross-domain. if your script is on the same server use:you have acces to the php of the server use `echo  $_GET['callback'].'('.json_encode($return) .')';`
else try to use [php] cURL;

Answer (score 0):

**please watch This Side Example I think usefull for you**

http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0a2/experiments/api-viewer/docs/jQuery.getJSON/index.html